# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags -- what is going on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, syntax-error

I am trying to create rows dynamically that when clicked load a view for the associated row.  My code (in javascript and jquery) is below

```
    var row = $('<tr />');
    var action = '@Url.Action("Get", "myController", new { myID = "__param__" })';
    action = action.replace('__param__', rowData.myID)
    row.attr('onclick', action);

    $("#ListTable > tbody").append(row);
```

The rows created look like this

```
<tr onclick="/myControler/Get?myID=113066"><td width="20%">12345</td><td width="80%">Test Text</td></tr>
```

However, when I click the row, I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression flags.
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here, as everything looks good.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: because onclick expects a statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `attr()` to attach an event. What you want to do is make a link when they click? So you need to set the page location.

```
row.on('click', function () {
  window.location.href = action
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onclick` attribute must contain JavaScript. In JavaScript, an expression that starts and ends with slashes, like `/myControler/` is a regular expression.